# how to list images on sd card sorted according to time

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

I can get the list of images in sd card using fololowing`

but these are not sorted

how can I get them sorted  either by name or time

thanks in advance

```
String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

            String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/somedirectoryname/";

            File targetDirectory = new File(targetPath);

            File[] files = targetDirectory.listFiles();`
for (File file : files1) {
                    list.add(file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be easier if you use the built-in content provider

```
     MediaStore.Images.Media.query(cr, uri, projection, where, orderBy)
```

something like this:

```
    String[] projection = {MediaColumns._ID, MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED};
    Cursor c = MediaStore.Images.Media.query(getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED);
```

then you can loop the cursor to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `lastModified()` method of File to get the time the file was modified.

**-** Store them in `Collection` like `ArrayList<File>`.

**-** Use `java.util.Comparator<T>` to **compare and sort** them according to **time and name**.