# Sort images according to date and display in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

In my code i have displayed the images taken from sdcard in a gridview.Now i want that images to be sorted according to the last modified date in ascending order.I tried using Collections.sort and comparator.But it shows error.
Her is my code
Iam retrieving the images from sdcard by this

```
 ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] listFile;

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/saved_images";


    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File i : files) {
        imageList.add(i.getAbsolutePath());

     }
```

And i tried collections.sort Comparator to sort the list based on date

```
Collections.sort(imageList,new Comparator<Object>()
            {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
                return +1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

            });

    lazyloadadapter = new LazyLoadAdapter(getActivity(), imageList);
    gV.setAdapter(lazyloadadapter);
```

But iam getting an error of java.lang.ClasscastEception String cannot be cast to file.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException error

Comment: Please prepare your query to get sorted list images using  MediaStore.Images.Media.query() check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824233/how-to-list-images-on-sd-card-sorted-according-to-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `String` paths to the list:

```
imageList.add(i.getAbsolutePath());
```

Yet when comparing, you are treating these as files:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
```

Change your list to be `ArrayList<File>` and the first line to actually add your `File` objects - and you should be ok:

```
imageList.add(i);
```

Of course, you may have to modify other parts of your code. Also, do specify the class for the comparator - change your comparator code to:

```
new Comparator<File>()
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        if (o1.lastModified() > o2.lastModified()) {
```

If you require to store the paths, then in your comparator you need to actually create the `File` objects - in which case change your comparator to:

```
new Comparator<String>()
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (new File(o1).lastModified() > new File(o2).lastModified()) {
```

On a side note, sorting files by last modified date is not the same as sorting images by dates, as images would normally store the date when the images were taken in their EXIF metadata and it's often different from the date of the file, which indicates when the file was create/modified on the device.

Comment: i changed imageList.add(i.getAbsolutePath()) to imageList.add(i)

Answer (score 0):

Implement comparator like below code for comparing files.

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
public int compare(File f1, File f2)
{
    return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
} });
```

Comment: so i think i have to change the type of imageList from ArrayList<String> to file.

Comment: you already have Files[] just pass in no need to fill it in ArrayList and then sort. Sort first then create ArrayList with Absolute Path of files if you have such need to create ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Sort file array before using loop

```
File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<Object>()
{
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (((File)o1).lastModified() > ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (((File)o1).lastModified() < ((File)o2).lastModified()) {
            return +1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

});

imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File i : files) {
   imageList.add(i.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            File f1 = new File(lhs);
            File f2 = new File(rhs);

            if (f1.lastModified() > (f2.lastModified())) {
                return -1;
            } else if (f1.lastModified() < (f2.lastModified())) {
                return +1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Modyfy

```
 Collections.sort(imageList,new Comparator<Object>() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                File f1 = new File((String) o1);
                File f2 = new File((String) o2);
                if (f1.lastModified() > (f2.lastModified()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (f1.lastModified() < (f2.lastModified()) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
});
```

**Desc :**

> You getting java.lang.ClassCastException because you instantiate array list as list which holds only String Objects :

```
imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: yes now i got it. i created a seperate file list and giveit to collection sort, now it worked